# Manually setting up ruby on rails eclipse

Tags: ruby, eclipse, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been developing RoR applications since beginning of this year, and I've been using vim and it's plugins to develop all of my applications. AFAIK, RoR has been build to be used with a simple text editor.

However, I have a project that keeps growing, so sooner or later, I think that an IDE would become a necessary tool to continue building my projects.

I've been researching on the internet, and Netbeans is not a good solution, because of it's few developers, today there is no more support for rails, and the plugins are quite obsolete.

I've found also EasyEclipse, but this projects also is quite abandoned, and rails plugins have problems to work properly with different Eclipse versions.

What I've been thinking -since Eclipse is a highly customizable IDE- maybe I could install a generic ruby plugin (since a generic ruby plugin may be stable on time) and manually customize it myself in order to use it for ruby on rails application (establish my gems path, ruby path, etc).

I've found **Ruby DLTK 5.0 Kepler** plugin, and I think maybe it is a good start point. But since I'm pretty new to Eclipse, I don't know which other tools/plugins are necessary in order to achieve my goal (¿maybe a *server* plugin?), nor the important settings that I must tweak up.

Does anybody know if it's possible to configure Eclipse this way?

Comment: Have you checked out RubyMine or is paid software out of the picture?

Comment: Yes, I've seen RubyMine, and it seems awesome, but I'm looking for some open source SW.

Answer (score 0):

There is RubyMine, it is great but not free unfortulantly